# convert XML to array with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml with below info;

```
<item>
<site>Cambodia</site> 
<city>Phnom Penh</city> 
<code>21000</code >
</item>
```

I want to get all the info from this xml and input them into array $data, then echo them one by one like this; site = Cambodia; city = Phnom Penh; code = 21000; but i don't know how to do it. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try SimleXml?

Comment: Thanks all , I have done it now. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will get your desired output by the following code

```
 $xml = '
    <item>
    <site>Cambodia</site> 
    <city>Phnom Penh</city> 
    <code>21000</code >
    </item>';


    $data = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);
     $array = (array) $data;

     foreach($array as $key => $value){
     echo $key .'='. $value.'; ';  ///output:- site = Cambodia; city = Phnom Penh; code = 21000;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just cast it to an array.

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$array = (array) $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick!

Using **xml_parse_into_struct** — Parse XML data into an array structure

```
<?php
     $simple = "<item><site>Cambodia</site><city>Phnom Penh</city><code>21000</code>           </item>";

     $p = xml_parser_create();
     xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
     xml_parser_free($p);
     echo "Index array\n";
     print_r($index);
     echo "\nVals array\n";
     print_r($vals);
?>
```

OR **SimpleXMLElement**

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

echo $xml->item->site;

$userArray = (array) $xml;
print_r($userArray)
```